# NodeJs проблема установки?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Не могу понять, что не так.
Вот это весь код:
`console.log("h");`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переименуйте папки (в пути) на английский язык. Проблема бывает очень банальная. Какая у вас версия Node.JS установлена?

Comment: 5.6.0 у меня версия

Comment: Какая-то древняя... Ну это не проблема.

Comment: Возможно. Сегодня впервые связываюсь с NodeJs

Comment: `npm init` и далее по инструкции...

Comment: потом `npm install`....

Comment: Если впервые, то пересмотрите внимательно любой ролик в youtube, о процессе установки. Ну как написал @Air начните с npm init для начала. Есть отличные скринкасты  Node.JS на learn.javascript.ru

Comment: щас вышлю внятный ролики по `nodejs`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbe_kxjr9us&list=PLhe16itim17eF_RhK93TuNpHnImg5bPdI

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_t4mQMC3Nq8&list=PLhe16itim17c9tvzhC4xHAhF64CuiuU4I

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILpS4Fq3lmw&list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg

Comment: Я со смартфона пишу, прям сейчас сложновато дать вам адекватные материалы для учебы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам!